# project topic for neural network for freshers?

Tags: project, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I want to start working on neural network for my final project I want a topic which could be completed on 2-3 months of work and also It should be of good understanding for a fresher, as I am new to this topic and I want to learn by doing this project. It should not be very tough to understand and start work.

Comment: Write a standard MLP (multi-layer perceptron) with basic backpropagation training.

Comment: ok I will gather more idea about it then I will start my work. Thanks Martin...more ideas are still welcomed.

Comment: You can use a simple function like the XOR to test your network, that helped me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple OCR using a Hopfield neural network.

A good start would be:

- [A comparative study of neural network algorithms applied to optical character recognition](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~babaoglu/courses/cas04-05/papers/OCR.pdf)
- [Hopfield Networks: A Simple OCR Application](http://www.blendedtechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/05/Hopfield_Networks_A_Simple_OCR_%20Application.pdf)

It is a relatively simple fun project.

It would be even easier if you could use `Matlab` and some of its modules. But even if you were to implement it in `Java` or some similar language, I think it should be doable in 3 months for a beginner.

In Matlab, you could start with the following:

- [Hopfield Neural Network](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ug/hopfield-neural-network.html)
- [Hopfield Two Neuron Design](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/examples/hopfield-two-neuron-design.html)

You will need the [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/index.html) which has to be purchased separately I think.

Comment: thanks jkbkot for your answer OCR seems good. Anyway now my manager wants me to work on Object recognition using neural network. He asked me to implement it on MATLAB first. Any help on that will also be appreciated ...thanks again

Comment: No problem, I added some links for Matlab and neural networks to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question should be **what** and not **how** you want to classify. Depending on the problem, you can choose a fitting classifier. It's hard for you to decide the detailed solution before knowing the actual problem.

Simple topics (depending on your personal background) can be text, audio or image analysis. OCR is quite typical (you can use the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) database for that, it's well researched so you can compare your own results). To get a general idea of what applications are out there, you should also definitely have a look at the [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) database. It has all sorts of data.

The easiest Type of Neural Network to understand and implement is a Single Layer Perceptron. To also classify non-linearly seperable data (which is needed in most real-world scenarios), you can use a Multi Layer Perceptron with 3 layers (in/hidden/out).

Comment: thanks malch I will look more into it.